# Remove duplicates using VBA not working anymore

Tags: excel, vba

i was using the below for a few days and it worked fine, all of a sudden this morning im getting "Application-defined r object defined error" I am trying to remove duplicates using column one in my "Assignments" tab. If it matters the data is in a table. But again whats odd is it was working fine 2 the other day and i do not believe anything has changed.

```
Worksheets("Assignments").Activate

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?  Have you tried either condensing (`Worksheets("Assignments").UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`) or expanding (`Worksheets("Assignments").Activate: ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select: Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`) the code to debug?

Comment: Do you have data beyond the header in the first used column?

Comment: Sorry it fails at the below
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

not sure what you mean by is there data beyond the header in the first column? If you are asking is the file blank then no there is data which is why im doing remove duplicates. I also know there are duplicates so thats not the issue either.

Comment: What I mean is `UsedRange` points to the utilized range of the sheet. So if your data is C1:F30 then `Columns:=1` means Column C. If Column C has no data past the header row then this will throw that error, even if there is duplicate data in Column D for instance.

Comment: there is data in the sheet from A1:BO264673 including headers. Ok so i deleted all rows and columns after my data and it worked... what do you think caused the issue all of a sudden?

Comment: Probably the `UsedRange` part, though what it was actually doing I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem if I have a table on a worksheet and data outside the table. I put a table in A1:C4 and then filled cell G15 with data. When I ran RemoveDuplicates, I got the Application Defined error. I guess that means you can't remove duplicates on a range that includes a table unless the range and the table are exactly the same range.

I generally only use UsedRange if I have a specific reason to because it's a little unreliable. It's never smaller than you need, but sometimes it's bigger. If you want to remove dupes on a table, call out that table's range explicitly.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable").Range.RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
```